# How do I get CPU utilization information via the API on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cpu

I want to write a app to monitor CPU utilization(e.g. every 5 second) on iphone, but I can't find out any API to do it,  Do you know how to achieve it by objective-c on iphone, Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats not gonna be approved by apple

Answer (score 3):

CPU Utilization is not available through Apple's public APIs. You can achieve a similar result by retrieving the amount of free memory as shown in [this code snippet](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/01/get-the-amount-of-free-memory-available/).

Comment: Thanks, But this is about memory, My request is CPU usage, :)

Comment: Well, you're out of luck in that respect. Sorry! :(